# How to convert joda DateTime in jpa native query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jodatime, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity with DateTime properties persisted with hibernate

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
@Column(name = "EFF_DT")
protected DateTime effDt;
```

This all works well and good for regular spring-data-jpa generated queries.

I am trying to add a custom native query

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wsa_circuit_state_history ch WHERE ch.eff_dt between ?1 and ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    Integer countEffDateBetween(DateTime start, DateTime end);
```

The error i get is when trying to call this is

```
 java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY
```

This is the same error i used to get with regular spring-data finders before adding the custom type mapping to my entity

```
 @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
```

How can i make spring-data-jpa/hibernate use the custom type mapping for parameters to native queries?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: @WojciechGórski No i didn't find a fix.  In the end i managed to re-write the query in JPA, and so then the hibernate @Type annotation kicked in to handle the type conversion `@Query("select count(ch.circuitId) from nz.co.vodafone.wcim.model.CircuitStateLog ch where ch.effDt between ?1 and ?2 and ch.state=?3")`

Answer (score 1):

Exactly I too got same requirement.And I resolved it by registering custom type to hibernate configuration.

For native queries,TypeDefs are not sufficient for hibernate to find user type.It needs Type resolvers to find its types.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wsa_circuit_state_history ch WHERE ch.eff_dt between ?1 and ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    Integer countEffDateBetween(DateTime start, DateTime end);
```

In this case,hibernate tries to guess type(org.joda.time.DateTime)  from type resolvers.

```
Type type = session.getFactory().getTypeResolver().heuristicType(typename);
```

As there is no resolver for DateTime.Then it is getting default type(serializable type).And the value of DateTime is casted to its type,that is serialized and persisting in DB,where it is failing due to large binary value.

To resolve this, you need to register DateTime type to Hibernate Configuration as

```
configuration.registerTypeOverride(new org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime(), new String[]{"org.joda.time.DateTime"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your property to java.util.Date like this

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
@Column(name = "EFF_DT")
@Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
protected Date effDt;
```

Then convert in your getter/setter

```
public DateTime getEffDt() {
    return null == effDt ? null : new DateTime( effDt );
}

public void setEffDt( final DateTime effDt ) {
    this.effDt = null == effDt ? null : effDt.toDate();
}
```

Native:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wsa_circuit_state_history ch WHERE ch.eff_dt between ?1 and ?2", nativeQuery = true)
Integer countEffDateBetween(Date start, Date end);
```

Comment: That's an interesting workaround to avoid using DateTime, but in our case we wanted to keep the field as DateTime.

Comment: Why can't you change `countEffDateBetween(DateTime start, DateTime end);` to `countEffDateBetween(Date start, Date end);`?  That would enable you to keep your properties as DateTime.

Comment: We are using DateTime, not java.util.Date.  Certainly if we stopped using DateTime and used Date, we would not experience this problem.  However, we wish to use the far superior joda DateTime API. My question is 'how can i make native queries work with DateTime', not using DateTime is not a solution this this question.

Comment: Also, i'm not sure using 'Date start' will work, as the EffDate field is of type DateTime, then parameters to queries on it must be the same type, or spring-data will not understand how to write a query from the interface declaration.  It may be the case that spring-data is smart enough to convert between Date and DateTime, but anyway, i do not want to force the interface users to pass Date objects, when the rest of the API uses DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation I resorted to writing a custom CompositeUserType which stored the Joda DateTime in two fields, a datetime field and a timezone field.

When the entity was saved it stored the time value in UTC and the timezone as the original value, on retrieval it did the reverse (i.e. it converted the time stored on the database back into the original timezone).

As you have identified above, although a query like "dateTime BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2" makes intuitive sense, of course it makes no sense in terms of composite types as you need to keep the timezone in mind. This was the reason I stored all values in UTC so I could always compare any two date/time values on the database.

Unfortunately, this meant that all the date/time query parameters I passed had to be converted to UTC.